# Eror 303 see other when trying to login

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, user, server-response-time

I face a weird issue with my joomla site, There is one super user can enter the admin backend but when I try to login with any other user after entering the user and the password it redirect me back to the same page to enter the credentials, after checking the network response I saw error without any explanation: Error code 303 see other

can anyone help regarding this,

Thanx

Comment: Also, when I try to login to the backend using different browser / laptop I can't access the backend, just I can access it with one user I exported all the user tables from old database to the new one....please advice

Comment: When you get a 303, the location field of the response should contain a web link to the "other". Also this should come when the original link you were supposed to go can't be shown. Have you checked those other users have the correct rights to log in to the back-end?

Comment: I test it with the superuser I used to login before, but after clearing the cache of my browser it stoped entering to the backend

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  This is happening to me in Chrome - but not Firefox